# How to preview image using xml gallery in android?

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I try to make a simple XML gallery in android platform, but I get an error that says:

> Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

I'm sure that the file location is in the right place `/mnt/sdcard/SketchCraft/MyDrawing 1.png`.

This is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <galleryPackage>
       <image>
          <imgURL>/mnt/sdcard/SketchCraft/MyDrawing 1.png</imgURL>
       </image>
    </galleryPackage>
```

This is my actionscript:

```
 import flash.net.URLLoader;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.display.Loader;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;

 var xmlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("XMLcth.xml");
 var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(xmlRequest);
 var imgData:XML;
 var imageLoader:Loader;
 var rawImage:String;

 var imgNum:Number = 0;

 xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

 function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
    imgData= new XML(event.target.data);
    rawImage = imgData.image[imgNum].imgURL;
    imageLoader =new Loader();
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(rawImage));
    mc_image.addChild(imageLoader);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your image name to MyDrawing_1.png from MyDrawing 1.png . 
I mean remove space from your image name.

Hope this will help

Comment: well it dose not make any different.